# create all possible combinations of values in columns from two dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have two pyspark dataframes dist_stores and dist_brands.  I have samples of the two dataframes below.  One has a date field and all of the distinct storeid and the other has a date fields and all of the distinct brand id.  Both dataframes are created from the same original dataframe smp_train_df.  I add a column 'jnky' to smp_train_df with only value 'a' so that I can join the two dataframes dist_stores and dist_brands.  My end goal is to create a dataframe with all combinations of storeid and brand id.  the max_dt is always the same.  When I run the code below to join dist_stores and dist_brands I get the error message below.  Does anyone see what the issue is and can you suggest how to fix it?  Or is there a better way to accomplish the goal of getting all storeid and brand id combinations?

code:

```
# get all store brand combos
# getting distinct stores and adding join key
dist_stores=smp_train_df[['storeid','max_dt']].distinct().withColumn('jnky',lit('a'))

# getting distinct brands and adding join key
dist_brands=smp_train_df[['tz_brand_id','max_dt']].distinct().withColumn('jnky',lit('a'))


dist_stores.show()

+-------+----------+----+
|storeid|    max_dt|jnky|
+-------+----------+----+
|     85|2020-05-03|   a|
|    127|2020-05-03|   a|
|    130|2020-05-03|   a|
|     87|2020-05-03|   a|
|     77|2020-05-03|   a|
+-------+----------+----+

dist_brands.show()

+-----------+----------+----+
|tz_brand_id|    max_dt|jnky|
+-----------+----------+----+
|        107|2020-05-03|   a|
|       3476|2020-05-03|   a|
|       3463|2020-05-03|   a|
|        358|2020-05-03|   a|
|        612|2020-05-03|   a|
|        227|2020-05-03|   a|
|       3452|2020-05-03|   a|
|         36|2020-05-03|   a|
|         99|2020-05-03|   a|
|       3432|2020-05-03|   a|
|       4167|2020-05-03|   a|
|       2909|2020-05-03|   a|
|        104|2020-05-03|   a|
|        141|2020-05-03|   a|
|       3618|2020-05-03|   a|
|       5290|2020-05-03|   a|
|        248|2020-05-03|   a|
|        203|2020-05-03|   a|
|       3519|2020-05-03|   a|
|        221|2020-05-03|   a|
+-----------+----------+----+
```

code:

```
# getting all combinations of store and brand
store_brand=dist_stores.alias('a')\
.join(dist_brands.alias('b'),
     (col('a.jnky')==col('b.jnky')),
      how='inner'
     )\
.select(col('a.storeid'),
        col('a.max_dt'),
       col('b.tz_brand_id'))
```

Error:

```
An error was encountered:
'Resolved attribute(s) max_dt#22095 missing from filter_date#407,min_dt#421,tz_brand_id#573,storeid#569,current_date#401,max_dt#429,qty#499,dateclosed#514 in operator !Filter ((dateclosed#514 > min_dt#421) && (dateclosed#514 <= max_dt#22095)). Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: max_dt. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used.;;\nJoin Inner, (jnky#22085 = jnky#22091)\n:- SubqueryAlias `a`\n:  +- Project [storeid#292, max_dt#429, a AS jnky#22085]\n:     +- Deduplicate [storeid#292, max_dt#429]\n:        +- Project [storeid#292, max_dt#429]\n:           +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, min_dt#421, max_dt#429, coalesce((brand_qty#470 / total_qty#452), cast(0 as double)) AS norm_qty#596, storeid#292]\n:              +- Join LeftOuter, (storeid#292 = storeid#569)\n:                 :- SubqueryAlias `a`\n:                 :  +- Project [storeid#292, min_dt#421, max_dt#429, tz_brand_id#296, sum(qty)#463 AS brand_qty#470]\n:                 :     +- Aggregate [storeid#292, min_dt#421, max_dt#429, tz_brand_id#296], [storeid#292, min_dt#421, max_dt#429, tz_brand_id#296, sum(qty#222) AS sum(qty)#463]\n:                 :        +- Filter ((dateclosed#237 > min_dt#421) && (dateclosed#237 <= max_dt#429))\n:                 :           +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, storeid#292, qty#222, dateclosed#237, current_date#401, filter_date#407, min_dt#421, date_add(filter_date#407, 60) AS max_dt#429]\n:                 :              +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, storeid#292, qty#222, dateclosed#237, current_date#401, filter_date#407, date_add(filter_date#407, 0) AS min_dt#421]\n:                 :                 +- Filter (dateclosed#237 > filter_date#407)\n:                 :                    +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, storeid#292, qty#222, dateclosed#237, current_date#401, date_add(current_date#401, -120) AS filter_date#407]\n:                 :                       +- Filter storeid#292 IN (85,130,77,127,87)\n:                 :                          +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, storeid#292, qty#222, dateclosed#237, to_date(cast(unix_timestamp(2020-07-02 14:57:04, yyyy-MM-dd, None) as timestamp), None) AS current_date#401]\n:                 :                             +- Filter isnotnull(tz_brand_id#296)\n:                 :                                +- Filter NOT (storeid#292 = 230)\n:                 :                                   +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, storeid#292, qty#222, dateclosed#237]\n:                 :                                      +- Filter (producttype#211 = EDIBLE)\n:                 :                                         +- LogicalRDD [cbd_perc#199, thc_perc#200, register#201, customer_type#202, type#203, customer_state#204, customer_city#205, zip_code#206, age#207, age_group#208, cashier#209, approver#210, producttype#211, productsubtype#212, productattributes#213, productbrand#214, productname#215, classification#216, tier#217, weight#218, unitofmeasure#219, size#220, priceunit#221, qty#222, ... 75 more fields], false\n:                 +- SubqueryAlias `b`\n:                    +- Project [storeid#569, sum(qty)#446 AS total_qty#452]\n:                       +- Aggregate [storeid#569, min_dt#421, max_dt#429], [storeid#569, min_dt#421, max_dt#429, sum(qty#499) AS sum(qty)#446]\n:                          +- Filter ((dateclosed#514 > min_dt#421) && (dateclosed#514 <= max_dt#429))\n:                             +- Project [tz_brand_id#573, storeid#569, qty#499, dateclosed#514, current_date#401, filter_date#407, min_dt#421, date_add(filter_date#407, 60) AS max_dt#429]\n:                                +- Project [tz_brand_id#573, storeid#569, qty#499, dateclosed#514, current_date#401, filter_date#407, date_add(filter_date#407, 0) AS min_dt#421]\n:                                   +- Filter (dateclosed#514 > filter_date#407)\n:                                      +- Project [tz_brand_id#573, storeid#569, qty#499, dateclosed#514, current_date#401, date_add(current_date#401, -120) AS filter_date#407]\n:                                         +- Filter storeid#569 IN (85,130,77,127,87)\n:                                            +- Project [tz_brand_id#573, storeid#569, qty#499, dateclosed#514, to_date(cast(unix_timestamp(2020-07-02 14:57:04, yyyy-MM-dd, None) as timestamp), None) AS current_date#401]\n:                                               +- Filter isnotnull(tz_brand_id#573)\n:                                                  +- Filter NOT (storeid#569 = 230)\n:                                                     +- Project [tz_brand_id#573, storeid#569, qty#499, dateclosed#514]\n:                                                        +- Filter (producttype#488 = EDIBLE)\n:                                                           +- LogicalRDD [cbd_perc#476, thc_perc#477, register#478, customer_type#479, type#480, customer_state#481, customer_city#482, zip_code#483, age#484, age_group#485, cashier#486, approver#487, producttype#488, productsubtype#489, productattributes#490, productbrand#491, productname#492, classification#493, tier#494, weight#495, unitofmeasure#496, size#497, priceunit#498, qty#499, ... 75 more fields], false\n+- SubqueryAlias `b`\n   +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, max_dt#22095, a AS jnky#22091]\n      +- Deduplicate [tz_brand_id#296, max_dt#22095]\n         +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, max_dt#22095]\n            +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, min_dt#421, max_dt#22095, coalesce((brand_qty#470 / total_qty#452), cast(0 as double)) AS norm_qty#596, storeid#292]\n               +- Join LeftOuter, (storeid#292 = storeid#569)\n                  :- SubqueryAlias `a`\n                  :  +- Project [storeid#292, min_dt#421, max_dt#22095, tz_brand_id#296, sum(qty)#463 AS brand_qty#470]\n                  :     +- Aggregate [storeid#292, min_dt#421, max_dt#22095, tz_brand_id#296], [storeid#292, min_dt#421, max_dt#22095, tz_brand_id#296, sum(qty#222) AS sum(qty)#463]\n                  :        +- Filter ((dateclosed#237 > min_dt#421) && (dateclosed#237 <= max_dt#22095))\n                  :           +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, storeid#292, qty#222, dateclosed#237, current_date#401, filter_date#407, min_dt#421, date_add(filter_date#407, 60) AS max_dt#22095]\n                  :              +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, storeid#292, qty#222, dateclosed#237, current_date#401, filter_date#407, date_add(filter_date#407, 0) AS min_dt#421]\n                  :                 +- Filter (dateclosed#237 > filter_date#407)\n                  :                    +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, storeid#292, qty#222, dateclosed#237, current_date#401, date_add(current_date#401, -120) AS filter_date#407]\n                  :                       +- Filter storeid#292 IN (85,130,77,127,87)\n                  :                          +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, storeid#292, qty#222, dateclosed#237, to_date(cast(unix_timestamp(2020-07-02 14:57:04, yyyy-MM-dd, None) as timestamp), None) AS current_date#401]\n                  :                             +- Filter isnotnull(tz_brand_id#296)\n                  :                                +- Filter NOT (storeid#292 = 230)\n                  :                                   +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, storeid#292, qty#222, dateclosed#237]\n                  :                                      +- Filter (producttype#211 = EDIBLE)\n                  :                                         +- LogicalRDD [cbd_perc#199, thc_perc#200, register#201, customer_type#202, type#203, customer_state#204, customer_city#205, zip_code#206, age#207, age_group#208, cashier#209, approver#210, producttype#211, productsubtype#212, productattributes#213, productbrand#214, productname#215, classification#216, tier#217, weight#218, unitofmeasure#219, size#220, priceunit#221, qty#222, ... 75 more fields], false\n                  +- SubqueryAlias `b`\n                     +- Project [storeid#569, sum(qty)#446 AS total_qty#452]\n                        +- !Aggregate [storeid#569, min_dt#421, max_dt#22095], [storeid#569, min_dt#421, max_dt#22095, sum(qty#499) AS sum(qty)#446]\n                           +- !Filter ((dateclosed#514 > min_dt#421) && (dateclosed#514 <= max_dt#22095))\n                              +- Project [tz_brand_id#573, storeid#569, qty#499, dateclosed#514, current_date#401, filter_date#407, min_dt#421, date_add(filter_date#407, 60) AS max_dt#429]\n                                 +- Project [tz_brand_id#573, storeid#569, qty#499, dateclosed#514, current_date#401, filter_date#407, date_add(filter_date#407, 0) AS min_dt#421]\n                                    +- Filter (dateclosed#514 > filter_date#407)\n                                       +- Project [tz_brand_id#573, storeid#569, qty#499, dateclosed#514, current_date#401, date_add(current_date#401, -120) AS filter_date#407]\n                                          +- Filter storeid#569 IN (85,130,77,127,87)\n                                             +- Project [tz_brand_id#573, storeid#569, qty#499, dateclosed#514, to_date(cast(unix_timestamp(2020-07-02 14:57:04, yyyy-MM-dd, None) as timestamp), None) AS current_date#401]\n                                                +- Filter isnotnull(tz_brand_id#573)\n                                                   +- Filter NOT (storeid#569 = 230)\n                                                      +- Project [tz_brand_id#573, storeid#569, qty#499, dateclosed#514]\n                                                         +- Filter (producttype#488 = EDIBLE)\n                                                            +- LogicalRDD [cbd_perc#476, thc_perc#477, register#478, customer_type#479, type#480, customer_state#481, customer_city#482, zip_code#483, age#484, age_group#485, cashier#486, approver#487, producttype#488, productsubtype#489, productattributes#490, productbrand#491, productname#492, classification#493, tier#494, weight#495, unitofmeasure#496, size#497, priceunit#498, qty#499, ... 75 more fields], false\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1587410022410_0092/container_1587410022410_0092_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1049, in join
    jdf = self._jdf.join(other._jdf, on, how)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1587410022410_0092/container_1587410022410_0092_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1587410022410_0092/container_1587410022410_0092_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Resolved attribute(s) max_dt#22095 missing from filter_date#407,min_dt#421,tz_brand_id#573,storeid#569,current_date#401,max_dt#429,qty#499,dateclosed#514 in operator !Filter ((dateclosed#514 > min_dt#421) && (dateclosed#514 <= max_dt#22095)). Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: max_dt. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used.;;\nJoin Inner, (jnky#22085 = jnky#22091)\n:- SubqueryAlias `a`\n:  +- Project [storeid#292, max_dt#429, a AS jnky#22085]\n:     +- Deduplicate [storeid#292, max_dt#429]\n:        +- Project [storeid#292, max_dt#429]\n:           +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, min_dt#421, max_dt#429, coalesce((brand_qty#470 / total_qty#452), cast(0 as double)) AS norm_qty#596, storeid#292]\n:              +- Join LeftOuter, (storeid#292 = storeid#569)\n:                 :- SubqueryAlias `a`\n:                 :  +- Project [storeid#292, min_dt#421, max_dt#429, tz_brand_id#296, sum(qty)#463 AS brand_qty#470]\n:                 :     +- Aggregate [storeid#292, min_dt#421, max_dt#429, tz_brand_id#296], [storeid#292, min_dt#421, max_dt#429, tz_brand_id#296, sum(qty#222) AS sum(qty)#463]\n:                 :        +- Filter ((dateclosed#237 > min_dt#421) && (dateclosed#237 <= max_dt#429))\n:                 :           +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, storeid#292, qty#222, dateclosed#237, current_date#401, filter_date#407, min_dt#421, date_add(filter_date#407, 60) AS max_dt#429]\n:                 :              +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, storeid#292, qty#222, dateclosed#237, current_date#401, filter_date#407, date_add(filter_date#407, 0) AS min_dt#421]\n:                 :                 +- Filter (dateclosed#237 > filter_date#407)\n:                 :                    +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, storeid#292, qty#222, dateclosed#237, current_date#401, date_add(current_date#401, -120) AS filter_date#407]\n:                 :                       +- Filter storeid#292 IN (85,130,77,127,87)\n:                 :                          +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, storeid#292, qty#222, dateclosed#237, to_date(cast(unix_timestamp(2020-07-02 14:57:04, yyyy-MM-dd, None) as timestamp), None) AS current_date#401]\n:                 :                             +- Filter isnotnull(tz_brand_id#296)\n:                 :                                +- Filter NOT (storeid#292 = 230)\n:                 :                                   +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, storeid#292, qty#222, dateclosed#237]\n:                 :                                      +- Filter (producttype#211 = EDIBLE)\n:                 :                                         +- LogicalRDD [cbd_perc#199, thc_perc#200, register#201, customer_type#202, type#203, customer_state#204, customer_city#205, zip_code#206, age#207, age_group#208, cashier#209, approver#210, producttype#211, productsubtype#212, productattributes#213, productbrand#214, productname#215, classification#216, tier#217, weight#218, unitofmeasure#219, size#220, priceunit#221, qty#222, ... 75 more fields], false\n:                 +- SubqueryAlias `b`\n:                    +- Project [storeid#569, sum(qty)#446 AS total_qty#452]\n:                       +- Aggregate [storeid#569, min_dt#421, max_dt#429], [storeid#569, min_dt#421, max_dt#429, sum(qty#499) AS sum(qty)#446]\n:                          +- Filter ((dateclosed#514 > min_dt#421) && (dateclosed#514 <= max_dt#429))\n:                             +- Project [tz_brand_id#573, storeid#569, qty#499, dateclosed#514, current_date#401, filter_date#407, min_dt#421, date_add(filter_date#407, 60) AS max_dt#429]\n:                                +- Project [tz_brand_id#573, storeid#569, qty#499, dateclosed#514, current_date#401, filter_date#407, date_add(filter_date#407, 0) AS min_dt#421]\n:                                   +- Filter (dateclosed#514 > filter_date#407)\n:                                      +- Project [tz_brand_id#573, storeid#569, qty#499, dateclosed#514, current_date#401, date_add(current_date#401, -120) AS filter_date#407]\n:                                         +- Filter storeid#569 IN (85,130,77,127,87)\n:                                            +- Project [tz_brand_id#573, storeid#569, qty#499, dateclosed#514, to_date(cast(unix_timestamp(2020-07-02 14:57:04, yyyy-MM-dd, None) as timestamp), None) AS current_date#401]\n:                                               +- Filter isnotnull(tz_brand_id#573)\n:                                                  +- Filter NOT (storeid#569 = 230)\n:                                                     +- Project [tz_brand_id#573, storeid#569, qty#499, dateclosed#514]\n:                                                        +- Filter (producttype#488 = EDIBLE)\n:                                                           +- LogicalRDD [cbd_perc#476, thc_perc#477, register#478, customer_type#479, type#480, customer_state#481, customer_city#482, zip_code#483, age#484, age_group#485, cashier#486, approver#487, producttype#488, productsubtype#489, productattributes#490, productbrand#491, productname#492, classification#493, tier#494, weight#495, unitofmeasure#496, size#497, priceunit#498, qty#499, ... 75 more fields], false\n+- SubqueryAlias `b`\n   +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, max_dt#22095, a AS jnky#22091]\n      +- Deduplicate [tz_brand_id#296, max_dt#22095]\n         +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, max_dt#22095]\n            +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, min_dt#421, max_dt#22095, coalesce((brand_qty#470 / total_qty#452), cast(0 as double)) AS norm_qty#596, storeid#292]\n               +- Join LeftOuter, (storeid#292 = storeid#569)\n                  :- SubqueryAlias `a`\n                  :  +- Project [storeid#292, min_dt#421, max_dt#22095, tz_brand_id#296, sum(qty)#463 AS brand_qty#470]\n                  :     +- Aggregate [storeid#292, min_dt#421, max_dt#22095, tz_brand_id#296], [storeid#292, min_dt#421, max_dt#22095, tz_brand_id#296, sum(qty#222) AS sum(qty)#463]\n                  :        +- Filter ((dateclosed#237 > min_dt#421) && (dateclosed#237 <= max_dt#22095))\n                  :           +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, storeid#292, qty#222, dateclosed#237, current_date#401, filter_date#407, min_dt#421, date_add(filter_date#407, 60) AS max_dt#22095]\n                  :              +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, storeid#292, qty#222, dateclosed#237, current_date#401, filter_date#407, date_add(filter_date#407, 0) AS min_dt#421]\n                  :                 +- Filter (dateclosed#237 > filter_date#407)\n                  :                    +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, storeid#292, qty#222, dateclosed#237, current_date#401, date_add(current_date#401, -120) AS filter_date#407]\n                  :                       +- Filter storeid#292 IN (85,130,77,127,87)\n                  :                          +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, storeid#292, qty#222, dateclosed#237, to_date(cast(unix_timestamp(2020-07-02 14:57:04, yyyy-MM-dd, None) as timestamp), None) AS current_date#401]\n                  :                             +- Filter isnotnull(tz_brand_id#296)\n                  :                                +- Filter NOT (storeid#292 = 230)\n                  :                                   +- Project [tz_brand_id#296, storeid#292, qty#222, dateclosed#237]\n                  :                                      +- Filter (producttype#211 = EDIBLE)\n                  :                                         +- LogicalRDD [cbd_perc#199, thc_perc#200, register#201, customer_type#202, type#203, customer_state#204, customer_city#205, zip_code#206, age#207, age_group#208, cashier#209, approver#210, producttype#211, productsubtype#212, productattributes#213, productbrand#214, productname#215, classification#216, tier#217, weight#218, unitofmeasure#219, size#220, priceunit#221, qty#222, ... 75 more fields], false\n                  +- SubqueryAlias `b`\n                     +- Project [storeid#569, sum(qty)#446 AS total_qty#452]\n                        +- !Aggregate [storeid#569, min_dt#421, max_dt#22095], [storeid#569, min_dt#421, max_dt#22095, sum(qty#499) AS sum(qty)#446]\n                           +- !Filter ((dateclosed#514 > min_dt#421) && (dateclosed#514 <= max_dt#22095))\n                              +- Project [tz_brand_id#573, storeid#569, qty#499, dateclosed#514, current_date#401, filter_date#407, min_dt#421, date_add(filter_date#407, 60) AS max_dt#429]\n                                 +- Project [tz_brand_id#573, storeid#569, qty#499, dateclosed#514, current_date#401, filter_date#407, date_add(filter_date#407, 0) AS min_dt#421]\n                                    +- Filter (dateclosed#514 > filter_date#407)\n                                       +- Project [tz_brand_id#573, storeid#569, qty#499, dateclosed#514, current_date#401, date_add(current_date#401, -120) AS filter_date#407]\n                                          +- Filter storeid#569 IN (85,130,77,127,87)\n                                             +- Project [tz_brand_id#573, storeid#569, qty#499, dateclosed#514, to_date(cast(unix_timestamp(2020-07-02 14:57:04, yyyy-MM-dd, None) as timestamp), None) AS current_date#401]\n                                                +- Filter isnotnull(tz_brand_id#573)\n                                                   +- Filter NOT (storeid#569 = 230)\n                                                      +- Project [tz_brand_id#573, storeid#569, qty#499, dateclosed#514]\n                                                         +- Filter (producttype#488 = EDIBLE)\n                                                            +- LogicalRDD [cbd_perc#476, thc_perc#477, register#478, customer_type#479, type#480, customer_state#481, customer_city#482, zip_code#483, age#484, age_group#485, cashier#486, approver#487, producttype#488, productsubtype#489, productattributes#490, productbrand#491, productname#492, classification#493, tier#494, weight#495, unitofmeasure#496, size#497, priceunit#498, qty#499, ... 75 more fields], false\n'
```

Comment: Can you please share how the sample output looks like?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to duplicate column names in both the dataframe. Ensure to rename before performing the join operation.Please use the following

```
dist_brands = dist_brands.withColumnRenamed('max_dt', 'max_dt_brands')
```

Then perform the join operation

```
dist_stores = dist_stores.join(dist_brands, 'jnky', 'left')
dist_stores.show()
```

Just perform a left join in order to get all the combination. You can further select the column you need likewise

```
dist_stores = dist_stores.select('storeid', 'max_dt', 'tz_brand_id')
```

Comment: I tried changing it to a left join and got the same error message.

Comment: Can you please check now.. Would be great if you cloud help accept this as correct answer once worked ..